# NaN in table, after drawing google piechart with JSON Data and SQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization, nan

I want to draw a google piechart with data from my server, in my case phpmyadmin. For this I used this example here:http://sophiedogg.com/creating-a-google-pie-chart-using-sql-data/.

This example is a little older and worked not correct so I changed some part (i.e. all mysql expressions to mysqli).

But the main problem is that this example shows almost only "NaN" in the rows.
This problem exists almost in the original example as you can see here: http://sophiedogg.com/graphs/

I tried to find the solution for several houres but without success, so I hope you guys can help me.

Maybe it is only a syntax error.
In my opinion the fault should be here:

(1)index.php

```
function drawItems(num) {
var jsonPieChartData = $.ajax({
  url: "getpiechartdata.php",
  data: "q="+num,
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
}).responseText;

var jsonTableData = $.ajax({
  url: "gettabledata.php",
  data: "q="+num,
  dataType:"json",
  async: false
}).responseText;r code here
```

or (2) in getpiechartdata.php and gettabledata.php at the var "q" or in the SQL where var q appears in the middle.

```
$q=$_GET['q'];
```

...

```
$sql_query = "SELECT nickname, name, j2.label, j2.pointsum FROM user JOIN ( SELECT j1.user_id, j1.label, name, hover, j1.pointsum FROM activityfield JOIN ( SELECT user_id, activity_id, label, field_id , SUM( points.points ) AS PointSum FROM points JOIN activity ON points.activity_id = activity.id WHERE points.user_id='" . $q . "' GROUP BY points.user_id, points.activity_id, activity.label, activity.field_id ORDER BY points.activity_id ASC ) AS j1 ON activityfield.id = j1.field_id ) AS j2 ON j2.user_id = user.id WHERE pointsum > 0 ORDER BY j2.pointsum DESC";

$sql_query = "SELECT nickname, name, j2.label, hover, j2.pointsum FROM user JOIN ( SELECT j1.user_id, j1.label, name, hover, j1.pointsum FROM activityfield JOIN ( SELECT user_id, activity_id, label, field_id , SUM( points.points ) AS PointSum FROM points JOIN activity ON points.activity_id = activity.id WHERE points.user_id='". $q ."' GROUP BY points.user_id, points.activity_id, activity.label, activity.field_id ORDER BY points.activity_id ASC ) AS j1 ON activityfield.id = j1.field_id ) AS j2 ON j2.user_id = user.id WHERE pointsum > 0 ORDER BY j2.pointsum DESC";

$sql_query2 = "SELECT nickname, sum(j2.pointsum) as total FROM user JOIN ( SELECT j1.user_id, j1.label, name, hover, j1.pointsum FROM activityfield JOIN ( SELECT user_id, activity_id, label, field_id , SUM( points.points ) AS PointSum FROM points JOIN activity ON points.activity_id = activity.id WHERE points.user_id='". $q ."' GROUP BY points.user_id, points.activity_id, activity.label, activity.field_id ORDER BY points.activity_id ASC ) AS j1 ON activityfield.id = j1.field_id ) AS j2 ON j2.user_id = user.id WHERE pointsum > 0 GROUP BY user.nickname, user.id ORDER BY j2.pointsum DESC";
```

or (3) at the creating of the table

```
  echo "{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"" . $row['nickname'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['name'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['label'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['hover'] . "\",\"f\":null},{\"v\":\"" . $row['pointsum'] . "\",\"f\":null}]}, ";
```

Maybe the fault is somewhere else but I want you to give some clues.
Please help me to find this.

Comment: `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: The code should be here. You're not returning numbers here (http://sophiedogg.com/graphs/gettabledata.php?q=28) so NAN(not a number) is correct. You also are open to SQL injections. You need to parameterize your query.

Comment: Ok, and how do i do this? Would be great, if you could give me some more information. I am not very good at coding. Thank you a lot.

Comment: This is a JS issue, not PHP/mysql. I'm not too good at JS so I'd recommend altering your tags. However, to me the issue is `"type":"number"` that should be a string in most of these cases. I cant go through the JS right now though and confirm how that `type` is used. Additionally that tutorial is terribly insecure.